# Search Edit Text like Google Play

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-custom-view, android-search

How to implement Search Edit text like Google play with Back and Cancel button on Right at place of Voice search and suggestions list should display below the complete edit text layout.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is SearchView with some customization
check the docs http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html

Actvity declared like this

```
<activity android:name=".SearchableActivity"
          android:launchMode="singleTop" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
                      android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
  </activity>
```

and SearchView xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/search_label"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint"
    android:voiceSearchMode="showVoiceSearchButton|launchRecognizer" >
</searchable>
```

Also you would need to override the onSearchRequested

```
@Override
public boolean onSearchRequested() {
     Bundle appData = new Bundle();
     appData.putBoolean(SearchableActivity.JARGON, true);
     startSearch(null, false, appData, false);
     return true;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The are some awesome libraries provide the Search view you want, like:
[Floating Search View](https://github.com/arimorty/floatingsearchview)

[image] [image]

And more:
https://github.com/lapism/SearchView
https://github.com/Quinny898/PersistentSearch